# CSS: Is there an equivalent of overlay for Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, overflow

One of the values of the overflow property `overlay`.

This value is supported only in Safari and Chrome.

I'm looking for an alternative for Firefox.

I've found an equivalent for IE : `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;`

Any help ?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow): "Only supported in WebKit-based (e.g., Safari) and Blink-based (e.g., Chrome or Opera) browsers."